# Stop creation of _notes folder in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: dreamweaver

There is a post in the Adobe Forum about this: [Preventing the _notes folders from being created](http://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-1671). However, the solution given there does not stop Dreamweaver from creating _notes folder everywhere.

> To prevent the _notes folder from being created by Dreamweaver,
>   disable the Maintain Synchronization Information and the Maintain
>   Design Notes settings for your site.

I already tried that with no luck. This is a known issue, is there any solution or workaround?